# Django url with multiple slugs, no reverse match error

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have a blog project in Django, and I want to be able to filter my posts based on the type of post, for example Travel posts, Programming posts. In my template I therefore need to filter the post by both the post slug, and the type slug, but I'm getting :

> NoReverseMatch at /
>   Reverse for 'getPost' with keyword arguments '{'categoryTypeSlug': '', 'postTitleSlug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['categories/(?P[\w\-]+)/(?P[\w\-]+)/$']

**My simplified template (getCatTypePosts.html)**:

```
{% block content %} 
  {% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.show_in_posts %} 

  <a href="{% url 'getPost' categoryTypeSlug postTitleSlug  %}">
      <img src="{{ MEDIA.URL }} {{post.editedimage.url}}" alt="image-{{post.title}}"/>
```

```
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

**My models.py**

```
class categoryType(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    categoryTypeSlug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categoryTypes"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.categoryTypeSlug = slugify(self.title)
        super(categoryType, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    postTitleSlug = models.SlugField()
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=True)
    body = RichTextUploadingField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category')
    categoryType = models.ManyToManyField('categoryType')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=True)
    authorSlug = models.SlugField()
    editedimage = ProcessedImageField(upload_to="primary_images", 
         null=True,
                            processors = [Transpose()],
                            format="JPEG")
    show_in_posts = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.postTitleSlug = slugify(self.title)
        self.authorSlug = slugify(self.author)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Views**

```
def getCatTypePosts(request, categoryTypeSlug='Travel'):

    posts = Post.objects.all()
    posts = posts.filter(categoryType__title='Travel')
    posts = posts.order_by('-pub_date')

    context = {
        'posts':posts,
              }

    return render(request, 'posts/getCatTypePosts.html', context)

def getPost(request, postTitleSlug, categoryTypeSlug):

    post = Post.objects.all()
    categoryTypeSlug = 
           post.filter(categoryType__categoryTypeSlug=categoryTypeSlug)
    postTitleSlug = post.filter(post.postTitleSlug)

    context = {
         'post':post,
         'categoryTypeSlug':categoryTypeSlug,
         'postTitleSlug':postTitleSlug,
          }

     return render(request, 'posts/getPost.html', context)
```

**URL conf**

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.getCatTypePosts, name='home'),

    url(r'^categories/(?P<categoryTypeSlug>[\w\-]+)/(?P<postTitleSlug> 
       [\w\-]+)/$',  views.getPost, name='getPost'),

    url(r'^posts/(?P<categoryTypeSlug>[\w\-]+)/$', 
        views.getCatTypePosts, name = 'getCatTypePosts'),

            ]
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that in Python/Django, the recommendation is to use CamelCase for your model names (e.g. `CategoryType` and lowercase_with_underscores for your field names (e.g. `category_type_slug` or simply `slug`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is occurring at `/` which is handled by `getCatTypePosts`. This view doesn’t add `categoryTypeSlug` and `postTitleSlug` to the context so your `{% url %}` tag gives an error saying the keyword arguments were `''`.

Since the `{% url %}` tag is inside the `{% for post in posts %}` for loop, you can use `post.postTitleSlug` instead of `postTitleSlug`. It's less obvious how to replace `categoryType` because it's a many to many field - it’s not clear what value you want to use there. You could probably use `post.categoryType.first.categoryTypeSlug`, as long as *every* post had at least one related category.

Comment: Thank you @Alasdair, may I ask when you say use, where do you refer to?

Comment: In the url tag `{% url 'getPost' categoryTypeSlug postTitleSlug  %}` which is giving the error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being really dumb here. Are you suggesting to alter the template to say<br> `{% url 'getPost' categoryTypeSlug=post.categoryType.first.categoryTypeSlug postTitleSlug %}`

Comment: As I said, you need to replace **both** `categoryTypeSlug` and `postTitleSlug` with something. You don't need to add the `categoryTypeSlug=`.